# Authorize LinkedIn API access in window application

Tags: c#, api, authorization, window, linkedin-api

I am creating a windows application in C# and I want to search the profiles in LinkedIn. How can I handle the authorization?

Answer (score 2):

LinkedIn supports [OAuth](http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1008), so you can start from there. Here's [an example](http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/1190) from their site.

Answer (score 0):

You can [webclient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28VS.80%29.aspx) to pass datas to the linked in url

```
 WebClient wc = new WebClient();
 //call URL with your data
 var res = wc.UploadData("linkedinurl", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(querystrings));
 //parse the returned results
 var result= System.Convert.ToInt32(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

If LinkedIn supports OAuth you can check my FriendFeed Win Mobile application.
I developed it with C# and Win Mobile 6.0 SDK and used OAuth to use FF Api.

http://ffwinmobile.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets